# Difference in SHA1 in .NET and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, cryptography, sha1, cryptographic-hash-function

I have a couple different bits of code but the short story is I insert some passwords into a MySQL database using SHA1 and also compute SHA1 hashes into .NET and they are not matching. I think this is a problem with my encoding code in .NET.

SQL Code:

```
INSERT INTO user_credentials (Password) VALUES (SHA1('password'));
```

password hashes to 5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8

.NET Code:

```
public static string GetPasswordHash(string password)
{
    // problem here with encoding?
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

    SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hashedPasswordBytes = sha.ComputeHash(byteArray);

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashedPasswordBytes);
}
```

password hashes to [?a??????%l?3~???

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm using this solution in my Windows 8 apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832306/simulating-mysqls-password-encryption-using-net-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the MySQL example you are encoding to a [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string, in the .NET example you are encoding in ASCII. The two encodings are not the same.

If you convert to hexadecimal in the .NET version you get the correct result:

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hashedPasswordBytes);
```

Result:

```
5B-AA-61-E4-C9-B9-3F-3F-06-82-25-0B-6C-F8-33-1B-7E-E6-8F-D8
```

Comment: perfect. needed to convert to lower and remove the -'s.

Comment: `string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hashedPasswordBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower`

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `[?a??????%l?3~???` in **HEX** representation. What you are printing is probably in binary form (hence the multiple `?` chars).

Try doing this:

```
string hexstring = BitConverter.ToString(hashedPasswordBytes);
```

And see if `hexstring` and MySQL hash match.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you an exact match to what MySQL produces:

```
 BitConverter.ToString(SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password))).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

Answer (score 1):

The SHA1 hashes should be equal, but the representation is not. MySql outputs a hex-string, so you will need to do the same in .NET:

```
return String.Join(String.Empty, hashedPasswordBytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")))
```

Comment: +manymany for avoiding that obnoxiously redundant `Replace()` thing!

Answer (score 0):

How is your MySQL table/database encoded?  Try setting both to UTF-8 (therefore using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes)