# Simulating MySql's PASSWORD() encryption using .NET in Windows 8

Tags: mysql, windows-8, sha1

PASSWORD() according to MySQL documentation is a double SHA1 algorithm.

In Win32 I was using this method:

```
public string GenerateMySQLHash(string key)
{
     byte[] keyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        SHA1Managed enc = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] encodedKey = enc.ComputeHash(enc.ComputeHash(keyArray));
    StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder(encodedKey.Length);

    foreach (byte b in encodedKey)
        myBuilder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

    return "*" + myBuilder.ToString();
}
```

SHA1Managed object is not available in the Metro .net framework because the security stuff is now in Windows.Security.Cryptography and not in System.Security.Cryptography.

In the documentation, I see this example to obtain the SHA1 from a string:

```
 public String HashMsg(String strMsg)
    {
        // Convert the message string to binary data.
        IBuffer buffUtf8Msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        // Create a HashAlgorithmProvider object.
        HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);

        // Hash the message.
        IBuffer buffHash = objAlgProv.HashData(buffUtf8Msg);

        // Verify that the hash length equals the length specified for the algorithm.
        if (buffHash.Length != objAlgProv.HashLength)
        {
            throw new Exception("There was an error creating the hash");
        }

        // Convert the hash to a string (for display).
        return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffHash);
    }
```

But I need a double SHA1 algorithm. Any way to do this easy as in win32?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution :), I hope it help you:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Reverse a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ReverseString(string s)
        {
            char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(arr);
            return new string(arr);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// MySQL PASSWORD encryption
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strMsg"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public String HashMsg(String strMsg)
        {
            // Convert the message string to binary data.
            IBuffer buffUtf8Msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

            // Create a HashAlgorithmProvider object.
            HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);

            // Hash the message.
            IBuffer buffHash = objAlgProv.HashData(objAlgProv.HashData(buffUtf8Msg));

            // Verify that the hash length equals the length specified for the algorithm.
            if (buffHash.Length != objAlgProv.HashLength)
            {
                throw new Exception("There was an error creating the hash");
            }

            byte[] arrByteNew;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffHash, out arrByteNew);
            StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder(arrByteNew.Length);

            foreach (var b in arrByteNew)
                myBuilder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

            // Concat with the STRING REVERSED
            String stringReversed = "*" + myBuilder.ToString() + ReverseString(strMsg);

            buffUtf8Msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(s3, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            buffHash = objAlgProv.HashData(objAlgProv.HashData(buffUtf8Msg));

            if (buffHash.Length != objAlgProv.HashLength)
            {
                throw new Exception("There was an error creating the hash");
            }

            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffHash, out arrByteNew);
            myBuilder = new StringBuilder(arrByteNew.Length);

            foreach (var b in arrByteNew)
            {
                myBuilder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            }

            stringReversed = "*" + myBuilder.ToString();

            return stringReversed;
        }
```